# buildFinished and buildStarted won't work

Tags: java, apache, ant

I made a subclass from `DefaultLogger` from `org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger` :

```
public class ExtendedLogger extends DefaultLogger {
    // My stuff
}
```

I took informations [here](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.7.0/org/apache/tools/ant/DefaultLogger.html).

So I overloaded some methods from `DefaultLogger` :

```
@Override
public void targetStarted(BuildEvent event){
    System.out.println("Logger : "+"[TARGET STARTED]\n");
}

@Override
public void targetFinished(BuildEvent event){
    System.out.println("Logger : "+"[TARGET FINISHED]\n");
}
```

**Which works great** (I can see the output).

Also these methods work :

```
public void taskStarted(BuildEvent event);
public void taskFinished(BuildEvent event);
```

But I have **troubles** with :

```
@Override
public void buildFinished(BuildEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Logger : "+"[BUILD FINISHED]\n");
}

@Override
public void buildStarted(BuildEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Logger : "+"[BUILD STARTED]\n");
}
```

Impossible to go in these methods !

Where am I wrong ?

Thanks.

**EDIT 12/01/2016 :**

I just tried a simple testBuild.xml like @Vaspar said :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="Init" basedir=".">



<target name="Init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <echo message="INIT-ING"/>
</target>


<!-- targets used in my project -->
<target name="Clean" description="Clean output directory.">
    <echo>Clean</echo>
</target>

<target name="CleanAutogenerated" description="Clean auto-generated folder.">
    <echo>CleanAutogenerated</echo>
</target>

<target name="AutoGenerateTopics" description="Manual specific targets.">
    <echo>AutoGenerateTopics</echo>
</target>

<target name="BuildDocument" description="Build full documentation">
    <echo>BuildDocument</echo>
</target>



</project>
```

And the output is :

```
Logger : [TARGET STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=Clean]
Logger : [TASK STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@12f33e1]
     [echo] Clean
Logger : [TASK FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@12f33e1]
Logger : [TARGET FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=Clean]
CleanDocumentTask DONE

Logger : [TARGET STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=CleanAutogenerated]
Logger : [TASK STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@1e2862f]
     [echo] CleanAutogenerated
Logger : [TASK FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@1e2862f]
Logger : [TARGET FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=CleanAutogenerated]
CleanAutoGenerateTask DONE

Logger : [TARGET STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=AutoGenerateTopics]
Logger : [TASK STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@19bf1ed]
     [echo] AutoGenerateTopics
Logger : [TASK FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@19bf1ed]
Logger : [TARGET FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=AutoGenerateTopics]
AutoGenerateTask DONE

Logger : [TARGET STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=BuildDocument]
Logger : [TASK STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@10b85cb]
     [echo] BuildDocument
Logger : [TASK FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@10b85cb]
Logger : [TARGET FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=BuildDocument]
DocumentTask DONE
```

Note that `CleanDocumentTask DONE`, `DocumentTask DONE`, etc... are pure Java outputs from my project (not ant).

As you can see, there are still no outputs from `targetStarted` or `targetFinished` :/

**EDIT 12/01/2016 (2) :**

Content of my **ExtendedLogger.java** :

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent;
import org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger;  


/*
 * This class has been wrote to deals with ant build outputs.
 * 
 * However, buildFinished and buildStarted seems not to work.
 * See details at :
 * 
 * http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.7.0/org/apache/tools/ant/DefaultLogger.html
 * 
 */
public class ExtendedLogger extends DefaultLogger {

    /*
     * public class ColorPane extends JTextPane
     * 
     * (personal class : JTextPane + Ansi coloring)
     */
    ColorPane colorPane = null;

    public ExtendedLogger(ColorPane c){
        super();
        if (c != null){
            colorPane = c;
        } else {
            System.out.println("ColorPane given to constructor is null. Exiting program.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void buildFinished(BuildEvent event) {
        ColorPane.appendInEDT("[BUILD FINISHED]\n", ColorPane.B_Yellow, colorPane);
        System.out.println("Logger : "+"[BUILD FINISHED]\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void buildStarted(BuildEvent event) {
        ColorPane.appendInEDT("[BUILD STARTED]\n", ColorPane.B_Yellow, colorPane);
        System.out.println("Logger : "+"[BUILD STARTED]\n");
    }


    @Override
    public void log(String message){
        appendInEDT(message);
    }

    private void appendInEDT(String s){
        /*
         * Detach the graphical modifications in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)
         */
        final String newLine = s;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                colorPane.append(ColorPane.B_White, newLine+"\n");
            }
        });
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            t.start();
        } else {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just posted a code that works fine. May be, you should start with a small example and scale up?? If you still face the problem, pls let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surprising. I used your code example and I'm able to get the buildStarted/buildFinished logs also.

### CustomLogger

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent;
import org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger;

public class CustomLogger extends DefaultLogger{
    @Override
    public void targetStarted(BuildEvent event){
        System.out.println("Logger : "+"[TARGET STARTED] " + event);
    }

    @Override
    public void targetFinished(BuildEvent event){
        System.out.println("Logger : "+"[TARGET FINISHED] " + event);
    }

    @Override
    public void taskStarted(BuildEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Logger : "+"[TASK FINISHED] " + event);
    }
    @Override
    public void taskFinished(BuildEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Logger : "+"[TASK FINISHED] " + event);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildFinished(BuildEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Logger : "+"[BUILD FINISHED] " + event);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildStarted(BuildEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Logger : "+"[BUILD STARTED] " + event);
    }
}
```

### build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="init" basedir=".">

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <echo message="INIT-ING"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

And the below is the output.

### Output

```
/DummyTest> ant -logger CustomLogger
Buildfile: /DummyTest/build.xml
Logger : [BUILD STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.Project@1318bd3c]
Logger : [TARGET STARTED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=init]
   [tstamp] Logger : [TASK FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@31623389]
Logger : [TASK FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@31623389]
     [echo] Logger : [TASK FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@636c7a8f]
     [echo] INIT-ING
Logger : [TASK FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement@636c7a8f]
Logger : [TARGET FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=init]
Logger : [BUILD FINISHED] org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent[source=org.apache.tools.ant.Project@1318bd3c]
```

Comment: I tried a simple testBuild.xml like you did, but that doesn't work :/ Anyway, thanks for your help Vaspar :).

Comment: Np. And thanks for posting the output. Btw, which version of ANT are you using?

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help. I'm not able to think of any other reason except method signature mismatch. These methods are available from the beginning, so version won't be much help. Check if you have the method signature properly `@Override public void buildFinished(BuildEvent event)` and `@Override public void buildStarted(BuildEvent event)`. In fact, it would have thrown an error, because of the annotation @Override.

Comment: The output that you see, as `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` and `Total time: 3 seconds` if you don't provide your **ExtendedLogger** - that actually comes from DefaultLogger. If that comes out there is no issue with ant, and logging abilities. The problem should be inside our code ExtendedLogger. But, I'm not able to think further. :(

Comment: Hi mate, I'm not sure to understand very well your last comment, in doubt, I added the content of my **ExtendedLogger.java** in my question.

Comment: What I meant was, you trigger the ExtendedLogger by calling ant, `ant -logger ExtendedLogger` - correct? If you instead call ant regularly, `ant` - what do you see as output? Do you see `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` and `Total time: 2 seconds`? - If yes, the **DefaultLogger** is working fine. Now, we need to worry only about the overriding class **ExtendedLogger**.

Comment: Thanks for posting the updated code. The **ExtendedLogger** instance is created inside the `org.apache.tools.ant.Main` class by using reflective newInstance. So, your constructor will not be called and possible your colorPane variable is null. - That's one observation.

Comment: Question 1: When you tried my example did you use your code for `buildStarted` and `buildFinished` or my code?? Your code has additional line of `ColorPane.appendInEDT("[BUILD FINISHED]\n", ColorPane.B_Yellow, colorPane);` Whereas I had just a simple System.out.println.

Comment: `ColorPane.appendInEDT("[BUILD FINISHED]\n", ColorPane.B_Yellow, colorPane);` is just a personal function to get the output in my personal `JTextPane` (ColorPane). Moreover, ant is executed from a `Project` from `org.apache.tools.ant.Project`. I don't execute my ant build by command-line tool.